# WriteConsole() weird characters?

Tags: c++, windows, console

I use this snippet to create a console from inside a dll. That dll gets loaded in a game.

[CODE SNIPPET](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/v-s/debug/article.php/c1249)

The console window creates fine. But when i write stuff to it, i just get stuff like "???D??".

I know i have to use the printf() syntax. So i use

```
wprintf("%s", "test");
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>Try using:</del>

```
wprintf(L"%s", "test");
```

as wprintf takes an wide character string as input

**Edit**: Based on the fact that the behaviour of %s and %S changes when used in wprintf what about:

```
wprintf("%s", L"test");
```

The %s in wprintf expects a wide character string this L"test" is. 
I removed the "L" on the format parameter since wprintf is defined as:

```
int wprintf(char *fmt, ...)
```

Comment: 'void wprintf(char *,...)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const wchar_t [18]' to 'char *'

Answer (score 1):

You're calling wprintf(), the "wide-character" version of the printf() routine. There's one nasty catch with these "wide-character" functions, in that the meaning of "%s" changes:

printf() - "%s" means argument is a normal string, "%S" means it's a wide-character string

wprintf() - "%s" means argument is a wide-character string, "%S" means it's a normal string

So your call to wprintf() is telling it that the argument is a wide-character string, but it's not: change it to

```
printf("%s", "test");
```

Comment: I doubt that the meaning of %s and %S changes depending on function called. The difference between the functions is that wprintf takes the format as an wide character string and printf takes a normal string.

Comment: At least on Windows (which is what we're talking about here), it does: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: It does this so its easy to compile both ansi and unicode versions of the same code: Tversionofprint(_T("format %s code"),_T("parameter"));

Answer (score 1):

A good habit is to use portability macro _T() which does nothing when we use ASCII and prepends all strings with L when UNICODE is defined. And using _t prepended functions which are really just macros that map to plain functions when we use ASCII and map to w prepended functions when UNICODE is defined.  That way you always have a portable code - which works in both versions:

```
_tprintf(_T("%s"),_T("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

the "%s" format string tells wprintf it should interpret the first argument as a wide character string.

To avoid these mixed-encoding problems, you can use the TCHAR macro's:

```
LPCTSTR pName = _T("World");
_tprintf( _T("%s, %s"), _T("Hello"), pName );
```

Answer (score -1):

Your encoding is wrong, as you are using wstring characters, but probably only have an ascii console. Make sure that you are using a unicode font in your console.

Comment: Ahh, i dont need unicode support so ill just rewrite it to ansi functions.

Comment: He's not using wstring characters as wprintf argument.